# How do you communicate between two unpaired Bluetooth Devices using RFCOMM in UWP?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

Over the course of a couple of weeks, I have been experimenting with bluetooth communication using RFCOMM between two devices running Windows Universal apps. In the course of my research, I encountered numerous claims (like the one found at the end of this [BT Developer FAQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth-dev-faq)) that communications can indeed be established between two unpaired devices by using the [RFCOMMChat sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/dev/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat) in GitHub.  Unfortunately, I have never been able to get even the simplest of tests to work.

Using the RFCOMMChat sample, I tried the following simple test:

1. Run RFCOMMChat on laptop (Win10 14393.576) as chat server (foreground) and click 'Start Listening'
2. Run RFCOMMChat on RPi3 (Win10 Iot Core 14393.576) as chat client.
3. On chat client GUI: Click 'Run', Select my laptop (listed), Click 'Connect to Selected Device'
4. Upon trying to connect, the laptop is presented with a pairing confirmation request and the app on the RPi3 dies (because it, too, is presented with a pairing confirmation dialog which kills the app).

Based on the claims that I have read, I would not expect to see a pairing request dialog on either device.

I have asked [this question in the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b017fefc-9335-46a8-bd0a-17fccbdbbc74/how-do-you-communicate-between-two-unpaired-bluetooth-devices-using-rfcomm?forum=WindowsIoT) (Windows IoT) as well.

Has anyone ever successfully established comms between two unpaired devices using UWP apps?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue and it works for me. Have you used a Bluetooth USB Dongle on laptop? If you have, what's the chip? You can check the [Hardware compatibility list](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/HardwareCompatList#Bluetooth-Dongles).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The laptop is a Dell Precision M6800 running Windows 10 Pro with a built-in Intel Wireless Bluetooth (driver version 18.1.1611.3223).  The Raspberry Pi running Windows 10 IoT Core is also using its built-in Bluetooth (4.1).  Were you using the same setup from a RPi3 as the Chat Client and a Win 10 laptop as the Chat server?  If so, what could possibly account for the differing beahvior?  I'm stumped.

Comment: Yes, I used the same setup from a RPi3 as the Chat Client and a Win 10 laptop as the Chat server. Receiving and sending are both working.

Comment: So, just to be clear, when you perform the steps, you are not presented with a pairing request dialog that requires a user to manually accept?  And the devices are not paired as you send and receive data successfully?  Thank you for your assistance on this.

Comment: Yes, I had no pairing request and communicated without pairing. [Be sure to "Request Access" to the device if the remote device is likely to become paired](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/dev/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat). So, a pairing request will appear or not depends specified device. You can try to use Desktop instead of laptop, or use two Raspberry Pi, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been notified by Microsoft that this is an issue with IoT Core and that they will notify me with more details once they have a complete answer. Unpaired communication between two desktops or a phone and desktop works fine.  This is specifically an issue with IoT Core.  Once I learn more, I will post their response.